# Installed apps frequently fail with similar error

Tags: contact, appexchange, error-messages

My organization would like to perform actions in Salesforce that are not included in the base functionality, so we would like to install Apps. Obviously we use well reviewed (4+ stars, many reviews, etc) apps only, and in the comments I cannot find people discussing these errors, so I suppose it must be on our end.

However, when I install the apps on our sandbox, I always get the following error when I try to use them to change contact information:

> MC4SF.Contact: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 1 with id a1036000004nATOAA2; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: [] (MC4SF)

Is this caused by something I can fix in settings?

(The most recent app that we tried and had this issue with is [Mass Transfer Contacts](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000019LqxEAE)).

Thanks very much

Comment: Invalid Cross Reference Id generally indicates that you are trying to populate a lookup field with the wrong Id, or with a null Id. In this case the exception is being thrown on a custom object with the prefix of a10. I can't determine what object that is, but you could enter https://YOURDOMAIN.salesforce.com/a10 to go to the list view for that object and determine what object it is causing the error. That might help you get started on troubleshooting. Do you have any custom code in your sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

MC4SF is the namespace of the Mailchimp for Salesforce app.  It sounds like it one or more of the following:

- a problem with your Mailchimp configuration.
- a bug in the Mailchimp app -- check that you have the latest version installed, and contact MC support.
- Mailchimp is working fine, but you could have some custom Apex code (As Morgan mentioned) that is firing some MC action using incorrect data and causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Just Uninstall Mailchimp from Installed Packages in your Sandbox when refreshing it, since that's not part of your testing anyway, only causes problems.